# isinstance with tee objects

Tags: python, tee, isinstance

As a part of memoizing mechanism, I have a generator, I `tee` it, and I need to check its type with `isinstnace`.

```
>>> gen = (i for i in range(5))
>>> one, two = itertools.tee(gen, 2)
```

then

```
>>> type(one), type(two)
(itertools.tee, itertools.tee)
```

as expected, but

```
>>> isinstance(one, itertools.tee)
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

so what is the instance of `tee`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we define a class `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass
```

We then define a function that overrides that class:

```
def MyClass(x=MyClass):
    return x()
```

If we call that function, we will get an instance of the original `MyClass`:

```
>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> type(instance)
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

It looks like `MyClass` is a class because the type of its return value has the same name, but take a look:

```
>>> type(MyClass)
<type 'function'>
```

`MyClass` is a function that returns an instance of `MyClass`, but they are different.  It is the same thing with `tee`.  `tee` is a function that returns an instance of `tee`.  When you see if that instance is of type `tee`, you aren't actually checking a class or a type; you are checking a function.  `isinstance()` will not allow that, so hence the error.  The way to get the class would be to create an instance:

```
>>> tee = type(itertools.tee(())[0])
>>> isinstance(one, tee)
True
```

Answer (score 4):

`itertools.tee` is a function, not a class (see `type(itertools.tee)`). It returns objects that are (somewhat confusingly) instances of a `tee` class, but that class is not available in the `itertools` namespace. I'd just grab it from an instance using `type()`. If you don't have an instance handy, create one. This seems to be the minimal amount of code to get the `tee` type:

```
TeeType = type(itertools.tee(())[0])
```

It does appear that `tee` consistently uses the same class for each invocation.

Comment: oh there is a way i guess :P +1

Answer (score 4):

`tee` is a function that returns an internal implementation type used by Python. In general, it shouldn't matter that it's a `tee` or any other `iterator`/`generator` type.

That said, if you really need to type test like this, you can do so, you just need to derive the "true" type of a `tee` instance the same way you checked the type already, by using `type`. For example, to store the type of `tee` instances in a variable named `Tee`, you'd do:

```
Tee = type(itertools.tee(())[0])
```

which calls `tee` to get instances, then uses `type` to get their class.

This is the only portable way to do it for the record; the actual types involve (being implementation internal) change from release to release; in Python 3.5, you have access to the raw type as `itertools._tee`, but obviously in your version, it's not exposed like that.

Answer (score 2):

isinstance is used to check whether something says it's a duck, regardless of whether or not it is a duck.

To answer your immediate question, isinstance.tee is a method, not a class, or type or tuple of types:

```
>>> type(itertools.tee)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

(In fact, on my version of python, class has altogether been removed from th list of options). Python is a 'duck typed' language. Basically, in order for 'isinstance' to say that something is an instance of another thing, it must inherit from it in some way.

Example:

```
>>> type(str)
<class 'type'>
>>> s = "foo"
>>> isinstance(s,str)
True
>>> class myString(str): #myString inherits from str (a type)
...   def __init__(self,s):
...     super().__init__()
... 
>>> s = myString("foo")
>>> s
'foo'
>>> isinstance(s,str) 
True
```

Primarily, these base classes that are inherited should be (wherever possible) base types or abstract base classes. Why is this? Well, Python's developers want to avoid a situation where we have a million new user-types like FooString and BarInt that people start checking for instance of. This should be avoided.

The ABC's provide a way of allowing an object to say it is something, like an Integral, or a String, without (necessarily) having to be a string.

But, Python's duck typing is built on implementing protocols. Protocols are defined by one or more "special" (or magic or dunder) methods in the class. Determining what special methods are part of a class can be done with dir(myObj):

```
>>> dir(itertools.tee)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__']
```

Or, even better, where possible, just try to do something with it, and if it fails, you know it's not a duck:

```
try: duck(something)
except: print("Not a duck!")
```

Answer (score -1):

`tee` is a function that returns an instance that isn't `itertools.tee`. One way to check that is (somewhat hacky) to query the class name of the instance:

```
>> one.__class__.__name__ == "tee"
True
```

Comment: As I noted on another answer, this is incredibly brittle; the internal name of the type changes from release to release (it's an implementation detail, not part of the spec, and can change at any time); in Python 3.5, the type name is `_tee` for instance.